# How can support Object.entries being called on an instance of my class - javascript / nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I am trying to get my class to behave like a "normal" object, in that when it is called in `object.entries` it returns an array of key value pairs.  After quite a bit of searching around I have been able to make my class iterable.  But I cannot find where to start in terms of implementing `object.entries`.

Here is where I have got up to,

```
'use strict'

class Person {
    #name

    constructor(name) {
        this.#name = name
    }

    get name () {
        return this.#name
    }

    *iterator () {

        var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))
        for (const prop of props) {

            if (typeof this[prop] !== 'function') {
                const o = {}
                o[prop] = this[prop]

                yield o
            }
        }
    }

    [Symbol.iterator] () {
        return this.iterator()
    }
}

const person = new Person ('bill')

//works - produces { name: 'bill' }
for (const prop of person){
    console.log (prop)
}

// doesn't work.  Prints an empty array
console.log (Object.entries(person))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your instances have no public "own" (not inherited) properties, which is what `Object.entries` includes in its array.

> I am trying to get my class to behave like a "normal" object, in that when it is called in object.entries it returns an array of key value pairs.

That's the default behavior, whether you create the object via a class constructor or some other way.

> After quite a bit of searching around I have been able to make my class iterable.

`Object.entries` has nothing to do with whether an object is iterable.

I don't think you can make `Object.entries` return `[[name, "value"]]` without making `name` an "own" data property. But you can make it a read-only own data property via `Object.defineProperty`:

```js
class Person {
    #name;

    constructor(name) {
        this.#name = name;
        Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
            value: name,
            writable: false,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
    }
}

const bill = new Person("Bill");
console.log(`bill.name:`, bill.name);
console.log(`Object.entries(bill):`, Object.entries(bill));
```

I've kept `#name` there, but there's probably no reason for it, so:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
            value: name,
            writable: false,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
    }
}

const bill = new Person("Bill");
console.log(`bill.name:`, bill.name);
console.log(`Object.entries(bill):`, Object.entries(bill));
```

If you want to be able to set `name` internally, just give yourself a private method that repeates the `defineProperty`:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.#setName(name);
    }
    
    #setName(name) {
        Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
            value: name,
            writable: false,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
    }
}

const bill = new Person("Bill");
console.log(`bill.name:`, bill.name);
console.log(`Object.entries(bill):`, Object.entries(bill));
```

Unfortunately, because the property is configurable, your code isn't the only code that can use `defineProperty` to change it. (This is rather like the `name` property on functions, which is read-only by default but can be changed via `defineProperty`.) So it's not exactly the same as having `#name` and `get name`, it's just close while providing support for `Object.entries`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining re Object.entries and public properties.  I had in my mind that because I was exposing getters that made these public properties but I guess this is not the way javascript sees it

Re the need for #name, I missed it out in my code, but its there to support setting the name.  So my class should have had     

set name (value) {
        this.#name = value
    }

.... (unless there is a better way of keeping track of the state...)

Thanks for the code snippets and will mark as answered

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't have to implement the iterator. The reason `Object.entries` wouldnt work is that due to the `#` the property is treated as private and therefore is not returned. If you remove the `#` `name` is returned by `Object.entries` like in the example below.

```js
class Person {
    name

    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}

const person = new Person ('bill')


// doesn't work.  Prints an empty array
console.log(Object.entries(person))
```

Comment: `#name` is presumably private and only exposed via a setter *for a reason*. This code also doesn't make a lot of sense, it creates a data property called `name` on the instance but also a `name` accessor on the prototype.

Comment: Thank you I misse the getter. If the property should stay `private` the name of the question should be more specific since it more relates to `how to return a private property with a getter when using Object,entries`